# How to properly remove many to many attribute via template/html?

Tags: python, html, django, django-tables2

I'm trying to figure out how to remove one of `ManyToMany` attributes from `UserProfile` usieng `Django-tables`.

Simple explanation:

I have a `UserProfile` which extends `User`. The `UserProfile` has `ManyToManyField` attribute `Language` so there could be for example 5 languages. I've created a table which shows these languages.

I can't figure out what to do to make able user to remove one of the languages and refresh the page.

You can add `html` into the column and refer to object in the row by `{{ record }}`. I don't know what to write there. I was thinking about `<a href="delete_language/{{record.id}}">Delete</a>` but I would have to redirect this back to the table so I couldn't use this view everywhere I want.

Do you guys know what to do?

The table:

```
class MyLanguagesTable(tables.Table):
    verified = tables.TemplateColumn(
        '{% ifequal record.level.name "unknown" %} <a href="/tests/{{record.language.shortcut}}">Take a Test</a>'
        '{% else %}  Verified'
        '{% endifequal %}')
    delete = tables.TemplateColumn('<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}'
                               '<button type="submit" name="action" value="delete">Delete</button>'
                               '</form>') # What to write here?
    level = tables.TemplateColumn('{{ record.level.get_name_display }}', verbose_name='Level')
    language = tables.TemplateColumn('{{record.language.name}}', verbose_name='Language')

    class Meta:
        model = LanguageLevel
        attrs = {'class': 'table table-striped table-bordered table-hover', 'width': '70%'}
        fields = ('language', 'level', 'verified')
```